# Joining the automatically broken lines by org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

With emacs/org-mode, I use `[[link][display]]` format to show and link whatever necessary. The problem is that sometimes, the automatic formatter kicks in, and break the line to have an ugly link as follows.

[image]

The solution can be (1) remove the leading blanks of the second line, and (2) join the first and second string.

[image]

How can I do that with emacs or org-mode? If org-mode has a solution to this problem, it would be better, as I don't need to delete `[` or `]` to make it editable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first solution is available as delete-indentation:

> M-^ runs the command delete-indentation, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `simple.el'.
>
> It is bound to M-^.
>
> (delete-indentation &optional ARG)
>
> Join this line to previous and fix up whitespace at join.
> If there is a fill prefix, delete it from the beginning of this line.
> With argument, join this line to following line.

With point on the second line, M-^ will remove the leading whitespace on the second line, the trailing whitespace on the first line, and join the two lines together.